# R - How to get total portion of year for overlapping observations without loops

Tags: r

We have a database in the tens of millions of rows in which the same policy can be implemented in overlapping periods.

We have something similar to:

```
Policy ID        Start Date    End Date
    A            01/01/2010    01/06/2010
    A            01/01/2010    01/02/2010
    A            01/03/2010    01/10/2010
```

We want to get a variable equal to the total portion of year during which policy A was "active", excluding the overlaps. We can create a new variable which includes the portion of the year for each observation.

```
    Policy ID        Start Date     End Date     Portion of Year
        A            01/01/2010    01/06/2010       5/12
        A            01/01/2010    01/02/2010       1/12
        A            01/03/2010    01/10/2010       7/12
```

We cannot, however, sum the periods, since they overlap at times: the result would be 13/12 by summing directly, whereas the real result should be the portion of year corresponding to 01/01/2010-01/10/2010. How to get to the result without loops?

We thought of using month dummies

Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago. Me neither, I did not manage to solve it without a loop, for me it was necessary. The solution was to calculate the unique continuums of the time periods per group (in your case Policy ID). Having that, you could calculate the activity period for the id variable. But it´s a loop solution..which you wanna avoid.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Library  lubridate to see the differences between two dates by the number of months

```
library(lubridate)
df$month  <-interval(df$`Start Date`, df$`End Date`) %/% months(1)

df$month <- df$month /12

df
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to have a look at [`aggregate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/aggregate) and [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).
The following link is a good [`aggregate` example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r).

A simple example can be the following:

```
# random data (two groups with random values)
d = data.frame(x=sample(c("A", "B"), 10, TRUE), y=-rexp(10), z=rexp(10));

m = aggregate(y~x, d, min); # min of y for each group denoted by x
M = aggregate(z~x, d, max); # max of z for each group denoted by x

out = merge(m, M, by="x"); # merge the two data-sets (like SQL `join`)
names(out) = c("x", "yMin", "zMax");
out[, "deltaT"] = out[, "zMax"] - out["yMin"];

# if you need to add the information to the original data, merge the output with the original dataset
d2 = merge(d, tmp, by="x");
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` you could compute the unique overlap period and `lubridate::interval` for counting the difference in months with approach from @MFR:

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")

#replace spaces in column names with underscore for ease in manipulation
colnames(DF) = gsub("\\s+","_",colnames(DF))


#compute minimum Start_Date and maximum End_Date for each Policy_ID
#compute interval period in months using lubridate::interval functions


newDF1 = DF %>% 
group_by(Policy_ID) %>% 
mutate(min_Start_Date = min(Start_Date), max_End_Date = max(End_Date),
overLapMonths = interval(min_Start_Date, max_End_Date) %/% months(1) ) %>%
as.data.frame()

newDF1
#  Policy_ID Start_Date   End_Date min_Start_Date max_End_Date overLapMonths
#1         A 2010-01-01 2010-06-01     2010-01-01   2010-10-01             9
#2         A 2010-01-01 2010-02-01     2010-01-01   2010-10-01             9
#3         A 2010-03-01 2010-10-01     2010-01-01   2010-10-01             9


newDF2 = newDF1 %>%
group_by(Policy_ID) %>%
summarise(uniqOverLapMonths = unique(overLapMonths)) %>%
as.data.frame()

#     Policy_ID uniqOverLapMonths
#1         A                 9
```